# Automatically trigging a close on lightbox_me

Tags: javascript, jquery, lightbox

I'm trying to use [lightbox_me](http://buckwilson.me/lightboxme/) as a message alert but, I'm having some problems getting the element to close after a few seconds. Is this possible?

Here's my code

```
$('#message').lightbox_me({
    centered: true,
    closeSelector: "#close-message", 
    overlayCSS:{background: 'black', opacity: .8},
    onLoad: function() { 
        $('#message').find('input:first').focus()
        $ele.lightbox_me();
        }
});
```

Ended up using this after help from Dunli, thanks

```
// test message
$('#message').lightbox_me({
    centered: true,
    overlayCSS:{background: 'black', opacity: .8},
    onLoad: function() { 
        $('#message').find('input:first').focus()
        setTimeout(lightbox, 5000);
        function lightbox() {
            $('#message').trigger('close');
        }
    }   
});
```

Comment: what error are you getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $('#lightbox_elem_id').trigger('close');
}, seconds*1000);
```